# list the content of folder and sub folder but i am getting proper o/p in console not in file it's not printing the sub folder content's

Tags: java

```
public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
        File file = new File("F:\\nitish\\out.txt"); //Your file
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory:" + fileEntry.getName());
                writer.write("Directory:" + fileEntry.getName());
                listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
            } else {
                int len = fileEntry.getName().length();
                writer.write(fileEntry.getName().substring(0, len-4));
                System.out.println("\t" + fileEntry.getName().substring(0, len-4));
            }

       }
       writer.close();
}
```

it's not printing sub_folder contents in to file

out put must be like:
Directory: xyz
Directory: a
  1
  2
  3
Directory: b
  1
  2
  3

Comment: Format your code so it is easier to read.

Comment: Try to elaborate your question a little bit be more as well. Visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you need help in learning how to write a good question.

Comment: is there an error? or else what is being printed as of now?

Comment: printing the contents in main folder but not sub folder contents in file im getting proper o/p in console

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Your question could be edited to get better help and be more easily understood. As I understand, your programme works fine outputting to console, but does not replicate that output to the file.  If so, show the console output formatted like code and the (incorrect) file contents and then people can help. Good luck!

Comment: @SrinivasMS, the problem is due to the writer being created everytime on each recursive loop even before the previous one is closed out.

Comment: P.s. Think about what creating the new FileWriter each time does. Look at the api docs, you can call a constructor with a second boolean parameter to ensure text is appended...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just modify the above code, then something like below should do the work for you:

```
public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {
            File file = new File("F:\\nitish\\out.txt"); //Your file
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    System.out.println("Directory:" + fileEntry.getName());
                    writer.write("Directory:\t" + fileEntry.getName());
                    writer.flush();
                    listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
                } else {
                    int len = fileEntry.getName().length();
                    writer.write(fileEntry.getName().substring(0, len-4));
                    writer.flush();
                    System.out.println("\t" + fileEntry.getName().substring(0, len-4));
                }

           }
           writer.close();
    }
```

However, I think you could keep a running variable(say of type StringBuilder) which could be returned from the listFilesForFolder method and that contains the text which is to be written to the file and then you could write that value out just once to the file at the very end.